# In AWS Lambda does the thread limit apply per lambda instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, aws-lambda

In this doc [Lambda Quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) it mentions that **Execution processes/threads** have an unmodifiable quota of **1024**.

1. Does this mean that if I have a lambda then all instances of that lambda combined can concurrently only use up to 1024 threads.
2. Or does it mean that each instance of the lambda can use 1024 threads. So if there are 4 invocations of the lambda at the same time they can use up to 4096 threads in total?

Comment: Second is correct, but have in mind that multi-threading only apply if you have at least 512MB of memory. 
Please, double-check the memory value because I'm in doubt between 512 and 1024MB.

Comment: @BAD_SEED Is that mentioned in the doc?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I will rephrase: when we reach that amount of memory the CPUs that runs our functions will be multi-core (so there's no relationship with multithread). I don't know if this is documented, it was something that one AWS evangelist said me a year's ago.

Answer (score 8):

Number 2 is correct. That limit is applied to each lambda instance.

Answer (score 0):

Each Lambda execution environment/ instance is given 1024 threads (regardless of the memory configuration)

Now considering each execution environment/ instance of Lambda is assigned 1024 threads, it's important to note that these instances stay warm between invocations (for a non-deterministic period of time). Therefore, it's important to close threads that are opened or make sure they are re-used appropriately such that you don't exceed the 1024 threads limit throughout entirety of the Lambda execution environment lifecycle.

For example: If upon every execution, you open a new thread/ socket and these are not closed, the subsequent invocation will open another thread/socket. If your function has high TPS, you can very quickly reach this thread limit simply because new sockets are being opened upon every invocation. It's generally recommended that you close each socket once the request(http for example) is completed. Alternatively, ensure that you manage these sockets appropriately if you intend to re-use them.